# FM Radio live streaming with phonegap in android

Tags: android, cordova

I am very new to phonegap application.I need to build a FM radio live streaming application.
I have searched through google.Actually I want to build application like FM India Radio in google play.But I am unable to find ant sample application.

Could someone plz help me how to do that with sample project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look into shoutcast or icecast. You should then be able to use html5 audio tags to connect to the stream.

Something like:

```
<audio width="300" height="32" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" src="http://insertyourstreamhere.com:0000/;"></audio>
```

from here: http://eventmedia.ie/basic-html5-audio-player-snippet/

Comment: I've tested this on both ios 7 and android 4.2.2 and can confirm it works fine

Comment: many many thanks for your prompt answer.Can u plz provide me   the code or tutorial how to work with phonegap.

Comment: There are a number of tutorials online, I like this one personally: http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/  It will give you a good grounding in phonegap. you could then do a little research on customizing the html5 audio tag to improve how it works.  If you found my answer helpful perhaps you would vote for it.

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to show a notification with a play and pause button when using html5 for audio streaming?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this https://github.com/devgeeks/ExampleHTML5AudioStreaming